Проблемы с импортом, что делать? (ImportError: cannot import name 'reshape' from 'scipy')
я использую пайтон 3.12 и хотел использовать pybrain, но получил ошибку, даже при условии того, что "scipy" установлен.
from pybrain3.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)

xorModel = [
   [(0, 0), (0,)],
   [(0, 1), (1,)],
   [(1, 0), (1,)],
   [(1, 1), (0,)],
]

for input, target in xorModel:
    ds.addSample(input, target)

print(ds)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\FTP\Listings\Листинги глава 6\Listing 6_3.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pybrain3.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
  File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybrain3\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .structure.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybrain3\structure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .connections.__init__ import *
  File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybrain3\structure\connections\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .full import FullConnection
  File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybrain3\structure\connections\full.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy import reshape, dot, outer
ImportError: cannot import name 'reshape' from 'scipy' (C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py)


А у него разве заявлена совместимость с питоном 3.12? Проект pybrain3 уже 7 лет не обновлялся, пробуйте с более старым питоном запустить его. На тот момент 3.6 только версия вышла.
